# SQL - Left Join problem

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT 
  tb1.booking_ref, tb1.investor, tb2.cost, tb3.product 
FROM 
  tb1, tb3 LEFT JOIN tb2 
ON
  tb1.booking_ref = tb2.booking_ref 
AND 
  tb1.investor = tb2.investor 
AND 
  tb1.investor = '12345'
WHERE
  tb1.location = tb3.location
```

The above query errors because of the references to tb3 - it works great without them.

Does anyone have any idea why??

Comment: You need a join condition between tb1 and tb3. How are they related? Also, based off your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865680/sql-select-where-matching-record-exists-and-no-matching-record), the `tb1.investor = '12345'` belongs in the `WHERE` clause, not as part of the join between tb1 and tb2.

Comment: Posted an answer based on your update.

Comment: Please don't use the old join sintax!!!!! When you do a migration sql from 2005 and beyond will have problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  tb1.booking_ref, tb1.investor, tb2.cost, tb3.product
FROM 
  tb1
      inner join tb3
          on tb1.location = tb3.location
      left join tb2 
          on tb1.booking_ref = tb2.booking_ref
              and tb1.investor = tb2.investor 
WHERE tb1.investor = '12345'
```

Comment: ^^ Shouldn't the WHERE condition be included as an AND clause as well, to make the query work on the maximum filtered data set.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of in the `WHERE` clause, add `tb1.location = tb3.location` to an `ON`/`AND` clause.

Answer before the question update: yes, it would.

Where did you state the relationship between table `tb3` and either of `tb1`, `tb2`? For joins, you need to have a relationship between certain columns among these tables.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you:

```
SELECT t1.booking_ref, t1.investor, t.cost, t.product
FROM tb1 t1
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT t2.cost, t3.product 
    FROM tb3 t3 
    LEFT JOIN tb2 t2 ON (t1.booking_ref = t2.booking_ref  
                    AND t1.investor = t2.investor  
                    AND  t1.investor = '12345')
) AS t
```

PS:- you need at least SQL Server 2005 for this.